# SQL Query with LIKE doesn't work unless % is at end

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL and learning about LIKE. I installed PostgreSQL and started running commands via psql in the command line. Everything works as expected, except the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM movie
WHERE mov_title LIKE '%an Beauty';
```

which failed to find the movie with mov_title = 'American Beauty'.

However, this one *does* work:

```
SELECT *
FROM movie
WHERE mov_title LIKE 'American B%';
```

Playing around, I realized that the query works if and only if the % is the last character in the string. However, looking at the documentation for LIKE, there is no need for % to be the last character, so I'm stumped. Would greatly appreciate some ideas.

EDIT: I was asked for some data, so here it is:

```
mov_id  |                     mov_title
--------+----------------------------------------------------
922     | Aliens
905     | Amadeus
914     | American Beauty
```

There are other columns but they are not relevant to the question. mov_id is the primary key.

EDIT 2: Here is info on the movie database. Apparently mov_id is not the primary key after all.
[image]

Comment: Could you include some of the data in the question?  This format would work if the title is exactly `American Beauty`

Comment: Try like this `SELECT * FROM movie WHERE mov_title ILIKE '%an Beauty%';`. If there are characters after 'Beauty' you query will not work.

Comment: Please include the definition for the `movie` table.  Do `\d movie` from the psql prompt.

Comment: Based on the discussion either use regexp (`where mov_title ~* 'an Beauty *$'`) or cast (`where mov_title::varchar(50) like '%an Beauty'`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that this movie title has some kind of trailing whitespace or other characters in it.  Try the following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM movie
WHERE mov_title LIKE '%an Beauty%';
```

If this works, then it means that perhaps something is following `Beauty` in the movie title.

**Edit:**

When using `LENGTH` on a `CHAR` column in Postgres, trailing whitespace characters are *not* included in the count.  This, along with a handful of other quirks, are reasons why it is generally preferable to use `VARCHAR` rather than `CHAR`.

Comment: @SalmanA I have no idea what your comment is supposed to mean here.

Comment: Never mind, it was for SQL Server. `select case when 'American Beauty ' like '%an Beauty' then 1 else 0 end` returns 1 on SQL server but 0 on pgsql.

Comment: @SalmanA for postgresql I think it depends on the column type,  char sometimes ignores trailing spaces, varchar doesn't.

Comment: Interesting. I checked and '%ican Bea%' works. So I would have guessed that there is a trailing character. But I selected the LENGTH() of the string and it is 15, which is just right, so it seems there are no trailing characters.

Comment: Update: ``LIKE '%ty'`` doesn't work. But ``LIKE '%ty%'`` does work. So there really seems to be an issue at the end of the string... yet the ``LENGTH()`` is 15 so there is no extra whitespace. Does there exist an invisible character which doesn't count towards the ``LENGTH()``?

Comment: @doublefelix Trailing whitespace are not counted towards the length of `CHAR` columns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Good to know! I just ran ``UPDATE movie SET mov_title = TRIM(mov_title);`` and still the same result as before.

Comment: Okay, I'm stumped. If I use ``WHERE mov_title = 'American Beauty'`` it finds the row. But not with ``WHERE mov_title LIKE '%ty``. And this is all after using ``TRIM()`` to remove whitespace at the front and back of the string.

Comment: Stop using `CHAR` and use `VARCHAR` instead.

Comment: So we found the cause. Thanks a lot for the help. I downloaded this DB from w3resource.com, I will let them know the reason in case they want to change it.